# Monitoring startActivity in logcat

Tags: android, logcat

I remember back in the day  with Android 2.x, it was possible for apps to monitor the logcat with a READ_LOGS permission. Apps could even detect activity launches from logcat. However, this stopped being possible with later versions of Android. Does anyone know which version of Android stopped this, and specifically what was done to stop it? Did logcat just stop displaying these Intents, or was it just no longer possible for apps to view logcat info not belonging to themselves?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting from Android 4.1 (Jelly Bean) logcat wrapped in Sandbox for security reasons, which means apps only allowed to read the logs generated by the app itself.

Comment: Which implies that there's no reason to read the logs at all, unless you're using a poorly-designed third-party library that logs information that is not accessible via its API.

Comment: Thanks. Do Activity Intents still get logged in logcat though?